# Creating a main page view with templates from Pycharm's Django IDE

Tags: django, templates, pycharm

I am trying to get template information into my view file and I keep getting an error that my output is indented wrong.  am i doing this right?

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
def main_page(request): 
   template = get_template('main_page.html')
   variables = Context({
       'head_title': u'Django Bookmarks',
       'page_title': u'Welcome to Django Bookmarks',
       'page_body': u'Where you can store and share bookmarks'
       })
         output =  template.render(variables)
         return HttpResponse(output)
```

I keep receiving an indentation error and i don't know what's going on.  thanks ahead of time for any help

Answer (score 1):

The traceback should tell you which line the indentation is on.

In the code you've pasted above, the final two lines are incorrectly indented. They should be in line with `variables = ...`.

Comment: when i do this, however, i get the red squiggly lines on the the last two statements except for output.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with red squiggly lines in your ide. The only other indentation tip I have is to make sure you are using spaces everywhere and not tabs. I hope you manage to fix your code.